# Python different case implementing question

Tags: python

Can someone help me get test number 5 implemented into my code where it prints the first eight numbers then it goes to another line prints the next 8 and so on!

[image: Here are the cases:]

```
numbers = [
   int(input("Enter n1: ")),
   int(input("Enter n2: "))
]

new_list = [ ]
def numbers_counter(n1,n2):
    if n1 > n2:
        pattern = ""
        pattern = f"Invalid value for n2"
    elif n1 == n2:
        pattern = ""
        pattern = (f"{n1}")
    elif n2 > n1:
        for i in range(n1, n2, 2):
            pattern = i
            new_list.append(pattern)
    return pattern,new_list
pattern,new_list = numbers_counter(n1 = numbers[0],n2 = numbers[1])


if numbers[0] > numbers[1] or numbers[0] == numbers[1]:
    print(pattern)
elif numbers[1] > numbers[0]:
    for i in new_list:
        print(i,end= " ")
```

Comment: FYI you can combine `>` and `==` with `>=`.

Comment: What's the problem? Loop from n1 to n2, have a counter ++ and print a newline every 8 numbers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks for how to group the list into chunks of 8. Print each chunk on one line.

Comment: Thank you will take that into account, can you help me how i can implement those cases in python!

Comment: Are you sure that's not because of a style and the task is to print all even numbers between to numbers?

Comment: FYI, you don't need the loop. `new_list = list(range(n1, n2, 2))`

Comment: I am not sure whats the actual thing you are asking but that code should print "40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54" as you asked, have you ran this code yourself?

Comment: you can also do this `numbers_counter(numbers[0],numbers[1])` since you're passing the value to the function.

Comment: @ThomasWeller how would i implemnt that? I am confused about that

Comment: @Barmar `n2+1`?

Comment: @stefan_mit_hannover ik i like doing it this way tho!

Comment: @It_is_Chris The loop uses `n2`, not `n2+1`.

Comment: @Barmar oops you're correct.  I was thinking  `list(range(numbers[0], numbers[1]+1, 2))`

Comment: Can anyone help i am so confused